# cloudSearch is there a way to use the result of expr in q (queryString)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I want to get the documents which are only within range of 0 to 500 
can anyone help me with this

```js
    let qs = this.serialize({
      'q': "nikhil+range **<distance <= 500>**",
      'expr.distance': "haversin(35.621966,-120.686706,latlong.latitude,latlong.longitude)",
      'sort': "distance asc",
      'q.parser' = "structured",
      'return': "distance,displayname,profileimageurl"
    });
    console.log(qs);
    return http.get({
      host: 'search-vegme-user-7l3rylms73566frh4hwxblekn4.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com',
      path: '/2013-01-01/search?' + qs
    }, function(response) {
      // Continuously update stream with data
      var body = '';
      response.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d;
      });
      response.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body);

      });
    });
```

Comment: I think the best you can do is to use the expr in your ranker such that documents that don't meet your distance criteria are severely penalized